# Display Messages with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I saw these on jQuery UI's themes page, and thought they were neat.

[image]

I wonder how to display messages with these styles both in a static way and with JavaScript.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using Chrome Developer Tools, I inspected the HTML of the error message. You can do the same for the other one or you can check out the [jQuery UI CSS Framework](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming/API).

HTML

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0 .7em;"> 
        <p>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" 
                style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
            <strong>Alert:</strong> Sample ui-state-error style.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
}

p {
    margin: 1em 0;   
}

strong {
    font-weight: 900;   
}
```

You can use the [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass#class) method to add these classes programmatically using JS. Also see the [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) methods which you can use to show/hide these messages.

```
<button id="show">Show</button>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>

$("#show").click(function() {
    $(".ui-widget").show();
});

$("#hide").click(function() {
    $(".ui-widget").hide();
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YKAnS/3/).

Answer (score 2):

I have adapted a short jQuery function to convert a given set of divs (containing text) into error/highlight elements.

You can see it in action on [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/774wH/).

Here is the javascript:

```
//function to create error and alert dialogs
function errorHighlight(e, type, icon) {
    if (!icon) {
        if (type === 'highlight') {
            icon = 'ui-icon-info';
        } else {
            icon = 'ui-icon-alert';
        }
    }
    return e.each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('ui-widget');
        var alertHtml = '<div class="ui-state-' + type + ' ui-corner-all" style="padding:0 .7em;">';
        alertHtml += '<p>';
        alertHtml += '<span class="ui-icon ' + icon + '" style="float:left;margin-right: .3em;"></span>';
        alertHtml += $(this).text();
        alertHtml += '</p>';
        alertHtml += '</div>';

        $(this).html(alertHtml);
    });
}

//error dialog
(function($) {
    $.fn.error = function() {
        errorHighlight(this, 'error');
    };
})(jQuery);

//highlight (alert) dialog
(function($) {
    $.fn.highlight = function() {
        errorHighlight(this, 'highlight');
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use firebug to inspect the HTML of that element. Looks like they're using `<div style="margin-top: 20px; padding: 0pt 0.7em;" class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all"> 
                    <p><span style="float: left; margin-right: 0.3em;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-info"></span>
                    <strong>Hey!</strong> Sample ui-state-highlight style.</p>
                </div>`

Answer (score 1):

Use [Jquery Messages Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-message/).It is neat, lightweight and simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the classes and HTML structure that jQuery UI produces, and make sure you have included  a jQuery UI theme.